# Are creation and annihilation operators unitary?

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, fermions, unitarity, grassmann-numbers

If a fermionic Slater determinant state is represented as
\begin{equation}|\Psi\rangle=|\phi_v\phi_{v_1}...\rangle\tag{1}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\implies|\Psi\rangle= c^\dagger_v|\phi_{v_1}...\rangle\tag{2}\end{equation}
Then,
$$\langle\Psi|=\langle\phi_{v_1}...|(c^\dagger_v)^\dagger$$
After using $\langle\Psi|\Psi\rangle=1$, from equation (1), the following must hold
\begin{equation}(c^\dagger_v)^\dagger=c_v\tag{3}\end{equation}
And then from (2) and using equation (3), we can may be assert
\begin{equation}c_v c^\dagger_v=1\end{equation} which implies $c_v$ is unitary. I know I am wrong somewhere due to some logic. How to identify it?

Comment: The creation/annihilation operators are non-unitary, hence they do not commute.

Comment: In the occupation number basis for your $v$ state, what you have shown is that $\langle 0|c c^\dagger |0\rangle=1$, which is correct, but to show $c c^\dagger =1$ as an *operator identity*, you also need to show $\langle 1|c c^\dagger |1\rangle=1$, which is not the case (it's actually 0).

Comment: got it. Thank you @MengCheng

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus You rather mean that since $c^\dagger$ and $c$ do not commute, the operator $c$ (or $c^\dagger$) is non-unitary. What you wrote is wrong. The correct implication is: If $U: H\to H$ is unitary, it commutes with its adjoint (more generally, it is a normal operator). By modus tollens, it follows that if an operator on $H$ does not commute with its adjoint, it is not unitary.

Comment: @DlIfE On a general note: For infinite-dimensional (complex) Hilbert spaces, the fact that some (bounded linear) operator obeys $AA^\dagger=1$ does **not** imply that $A$ is unitary. The canonical counter examples are the so-called shift operators on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. On finite-dimensional spaces, though, the condition suffices.

Comment: @MengCheng Consider to spell this out as an answer.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Good point! I of course meant that since they do not commute they cannot be unitary, but that's not what came out.